# how to break out of while statement only after all the substatements inside it are executed

Tags: python, loops, time, while-loop, break

I have this code, I want to break out of while only after `if, elif and elif` all are executed in it one by one. But if i have a break statement after `elif` as shown, the while loop breaks after executing `IF`.
How can I do it?

```
time_end = time.time() + 3
tm_end = time.time() + 6
t_end = time.time() + 13

while time.time() <= t_end:
    if time.time() <= time_end:
        change_state(7)
        
    elif time.time() <= tm_end:
        change_state(2)
           
    elif time.time() <= t_end:
        change_state(8)
    break
```

Comment: You can use `continue`.

Comment: @pppig tried continue. does not work. because it is already inside one more loop

Comment: @MateenUlhaq but it does not work too. tried

Comment: I vote to reopen because I don't find the question to be unclear.

Comment: How many times do you want to execute `change_state`? Three times? As it is currently written, `change_state` will run a very large number of times.

Comment: i want it to run 3 times in this loop but each time only for specified time and break

Comment: your `if/elif/else` has no sense bacause all of them check then same `time.time() <= time_end` and it will always execute only first `if` . You should add something more to run it - like `if step == 0 and ...: step+=1 ... elif step == 1 and ... : step+=1 ... `

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions :

```
time_end = time.time() + 3
tm_end = time.time() + 6
t_end = time.time() + 13

flag = [0, 0, 0]
while time.time() <= t_end:
    if time.time() <= time_end:
        change_state(7)
        flag[0]  = 1
        
    elif time.time() <= tm_end:
        change_state(2)
        flag[1] = 1
           
    elif time.time() <= t_end:
        change_state(8)
        flag[2] = 1
    if sum(flag) == 3:
        break
```

I have added a list `flag` which ends the while loop only if all the `if`/`elif` statements are executed at least once.

Comment: Is this functionally different from OP's example (minus the break)?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Sorry, but I did not get who is OP

Comment: Original Poster.

Comment: Okay!   The difference in the functionality is that my code stops executing only when all the `if`/`elif` statements are executed at least once, while the original poster's code does not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Notice that the comparison signs are inverted.

```
counter = 0

while counter != 3:
    t = time.time()

    if counter == 0 and t >= time_end:
        change_state(7)
        counter = 1
        
    if counter == 1 and t >= tm_end:
        change_state(2)
        counter = 2
           
    if counter == 2 and t >= t_end:
        change_state(8)
        counter = 3
```

---

A simpler way to write this:

```
transitions = [time_end, tm_end, t_end]
states = [7, 2, 8]
counter = 0

while counter != 3:
    t = time.time()

    if t >= transitions[counter]:
        change_state(states[counter])
        counter += 1
```

It might also be a good idea to throw a `sleep(POLL_RATE)` into the loop to prevent consuming all the CPU time busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to indent your break, like so:

```
time_end = time.time() + 3
tm_end = time.time() + 6
t_end = time.time() + 13

while time.time() <= t_end:
    if time.time() <= time_end:
        change_state(7)
        
    elif time.time() <= tm_end:
        change_state(2)
           
    elif time.time() <= t_end:
        change_state(8)

    elif time.time() == t_end 
        break # break when the end of time.time() is reached
```

Comment: This should do exactly the same thing as the original post.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq the code from the original post breaks after the first 'if' statement, this code will break after the last 'elif' statement, so it does not do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Clarius333 this just breaks immediately after entering the last loop and does not execute the last loop for the required time interval

Comment: @siddharth in that case, what about just exiting on elif time.time() == t_end? If included, this loop stops after 109376 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the time deltas instead, paired with the respective states, and then use a `while` loop to keep changing the state until the time delta expires:

```
start = time.time()
for delta, state in (3, 7), (6, 2), (13, 8):
   while time.time() - start <= delta:
       change_state(state)
```